How to remove BSD games from ubuntu
I have some games that came with my distro (bsd gmes) and i would like to remove them, but idk how...
Could someone guide me on how to do it pls?
I'm using ubuntu burdie.

Assuming you're using Ubuntu, this should do exactly what you're asking:
sudo apt remove bsdgames bsdgames-nonfree

